# Footprint assignments in KiCad

Tags: potentiometer, kicad, footprint

Does anyone know what footprint assignment for the potentiometer WH148 style in KiCad? There were a lot of footprints but I don't know which one is the same as the WH148 style.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the datasheet for the WH148 pot to see the recommended footprint, then search through the footprints provided by KiCad to find a footprint that matches the datasheet.  You will likely find some pattern to KiCAD's footprint names that will ease your search.

It may be easier to make your own footprint - if you do any amount of PCB layout work, you WILL have to make some of your own footprints.

Answer (score 2):

If we take a look at the [datasheet](https://www.handsontec.com/dataspecs/passive/WH148%20Pot-meter.pdf) for the WH148 series, we can see that the recommended footprint is just 3 through-holes with a 5 mm pitch and a 1.2 mm diameter.

[image]

This is identical to the KiCAD footprint for the Alps RK163 (Potentiometer_Alps_RK163_Single_Horizontal).

[image]
(Source: [rs-online](https://docs.rs-online.com/6491/A700000006802122.pdf))

Keep in mind though that there are different shaft length available, so the silkscreen might not match the actual length.